# use of undeclared crate or module 'gst'

Tags: rust, gstreamer, rust-cargo, gstreamer-rs

I'm trying to run [gstreamer crate](https://crates.io/crates/gstreamer#installation) on macOS (latest version)

but getting `use of undeclared crate or module gst`

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "gstreamerDemo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"



[dependencies]
gstreamer = "0.20.2"


[target.'cfg(target_os = "macos")'.dependencies]
cocoa = "0.24"
objc = "0.2.7"
```

gstreamer is installed using the binaries (and not homebrew)

```
❯ pwd
/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework
```

added dependencies using `cargo add gstreamer`

code:

```
use gst::prelude::*;

fn main() {
  get::init().unwrap();
}
```

error:

```
use gst::prelude::*;
^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `gst`
```

Comment: You must share the code snippet where you are getting this error. Try replacing/adding `use gstreamer`  with `use gstreamer as gst` in your code.

Comment: it's just the tutorial examples. added the relevant code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot import a dependency `gstreamer` in your `Cargo.toml` and use it as `gst` in your source code. You could however rename it, either by directly adding it with

```bash
cargo add gstreamer --rename gst
```

or by editing the `Cargo.toml` directly remove the `gstreamer = "0.20.2"` and add the following instead:

```ini
[dependencies]
gst = { version = "0.20.2", package = "gstreamer" }
```

Of course instead of renaming you could also use the crates actual name:

```rust
use gstreamer::prelude::*;
```